# Configuring Multiple MySQL Instances Using systemd, But how to use mysql client connect?

Tags: mysql

Configuring Multiple MySQL Instances Using systemd, [mysql-documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html),But how to use mysql client connect?

```
vim /etc/my.cnf

[mysqld@replica01]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-replica01
socket=/var/lib/mysql-replica01/mysql.sock
port=3307
log-error=/var/log/mysqld-replica01.log

[mysqld@replica02]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-replica02
socket=/var/lib/mysql-replica02/mysql.sock
port=3308
log-error=/var/log/mysqld-replica02.log

systemctl start mysqld@replica01
```

if I do this

`shell> mysql -uroot -P3307`

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: mysql -uroot -P3307 --socket=/var/lib/mysql-replica02/mysql.sock

Comment: I try to do the same, on ubuntu, but I guess some configuration is related to systemd service template (with @), and also apparmor has to be configured in order to let the service use the various files dedicated to the new instance (pid, socket, data, log, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` client will try to use socket connect by default, despite having received the port parameter in command line. You will need to instruct it to use tcp connection.

Either

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307`

or

`mysql --protocol tcp -P 3307`

will do it.

Another way to do it is to avoid tcp configuration parameters, and pass -S (--socket) pointing to socket for your desired instance. In this specific case:

`mysql -S /var/lib/mysql-replica01/mysql.sock`